# Android 14: SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener never called during installation

Tags: android, dynamic-feature

In my Android native application written in Java in which `Dynamic features` are downloaded on demand. Whilst downloading the progress is displayed with the help of `com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener`. This listener is then registered with a `com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager`.

The problem which I am having: the implemented `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener` works great on Android 13, but is never called on Android 14. My question is: why is this so?

This is how the split manager listener is registered:

`splitInstallManager.registerListener(splitInstallStateUpdatedListener);`

The implementation of the `SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener` looks more or less like this:

```
return new SplitInstallStateUpdatedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onStateUpdate(SplitInstallSessionState state) {
Log.i(TAG, String.format("SplitInstallSessionState %s", state));

    if (state.sessionId() == mySessionId[0]) {
        List<String> moduleNames = state.moduleNames();
            switch (state.status()) {
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADING:                           
                    
                    application.setInstallingModule(module);
                    progressBarHandler.displayLoadingState(state, context.getString(R.string.bundle_download_downloading, getReadableModule(module, context)));
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.DOWNLOADED:
                    application.setInstallingModule(module);
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.REQUIRES_USER_CONFIRMATION:
                    try {
                        splitInstallManager.startConfirmationDialogForResult(state, context, CONFIRMATION_REQUEST_CODE);
                    } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "Could not send confirmation intent for download of module.");
                    }
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLING:
                    application.setInstallingModule(module);
                    progressBarHandler.displayLoadingState(state, context.getString(R.string.bundle_download_installing, getReadableModule(module, context)));
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.INSTALLED:
                    application.setInstallingModule(null);
                    reportInstallSuccess(context, module);
                    progressBarHandler.hideProgress();
                    splitInstallManager.unregisterListener(this);
                    operation.run();
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.FAILED:
                    application.setInstallingModule(null);
                    progressBarHandler.hideProgress();
                    FancyToast.makeText(context, String.format(context.getString(R.string.bundle_install_failed_message), getReadableModule(module, context)),
                            FancyToast.LENGTH_LONG, FancyToast.ERROR, false).show();
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELING:
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Cancelling installation of modules (%s)", moduleNames));
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.CANCELED:
                    application.setInstallingModule(null);
                    progressBarHandler.hideProgress();
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.i(TAG, String.format("Other status for (%s): %d", moduleNames, state.status()));
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.PENDING:
                    break;
                case SplitInstallSessionStatus.UNKNOWN:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have test on a Google Pixel 7 phone with Android 14.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the usage of the outdated `com.google.android.play:core:1.10.3` library.

I have replaced it with the newer libraries:

```
implementation "com.google.android.play:feature-delivery:2.1.0"
implementation "com.google.android.play:review:2.0.1"
```

After this the `splitInstallStateUpdatedListener` started working in Android 14.

See more info here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore